# sync width of xAxis between two charts, when one chart has multiple yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have two highcharts on one page one of the charts can add and remove a second or thrid yAxis dynamicly. When this is done of course the width of the xAxis is shorter than the one with only one yAxis. 
Now i want to sync the width of the xAxis to keep both charts underneath each other. 
When I try the set xAxis width the width is changed but the chartarea is sticking to the left and not to the right.
How can I get draw both chart-areas with the same dimensions?

Here is a fiddle with a small example:    `Fiddle`    [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cvCX/753/)

Best
   MrLight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `top`, `width` and `offset` properties to size and position axes. First two of these are not documented but they work.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cvey8ap8/

```
xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jane', 'John', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'jim'],
      width: '90%',
      left: '8%',

    // Categories for the charts
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0, // Lowest value to show on the yAxis
        title: {
          text: 'Apple Consumption' // Title for the yAxis
        },
        left: '7%',
        offset: 0
      },
      {
        min: 0, // Lowest value to show on the yAxis
        title: {
          text: 'Apple12 Consumption' // Title for the yAxis
        },
        offset: 0

      }
    ],
```

Comment: Thats working! Still having trouble to set the left / offset values dynamicly but as shown in the fiddle your solution is working quiete easy! THANXs

Comment: Interesting solution, I also have trouble calculating the correct left value, as in your example, the yAxis labels my differ.